# Licenses required for an asp.net web server

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, licensing

What are the licences required for an asp.net (MVC) web application using sql server running a windows server ? Is Windows **Web** Server 2008 R2 enough for running SQL Server 2008 Web ? Is it possible (legal ?!) to install SQL Server on a "Web" operating system ? What are the limitations ? An official link would be nice

Comment: What is "SQL Server 2008 Web"? What is "Windows Web Server 2008 R2"? There is "Windows Server 2008 R2" and "SQL Server 2008". There are no web specific versions.

Comment: windows server editions: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/pricing.aspx 
sql server editions: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/pricing.aspx

Comment: @Oded - yes, there are, web SKU for server was introduced, I think, with 2008, can't remember when the SQL version was introduced.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked to a lawyer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catalin - you were one link away from the answer for licensing SQL Server on Windows Web Server:

On this page: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-overview.aspx you'll find the following:

"Windows Web Server 2008 licensing is enhanced to allow any type of database software on the server software with no limit on the number of users"

For SQL Server - you have to have a processor license as the number of clients for a web application is unknown (as a generalisation) so the CAL model doesn't work.

In terms of what you can do with the web edition (if express isn't sufficient and it often is) this is the page you want (specifically the Licensing section near the end of the page):

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/web.aspx